# Finding out the difference between data points

Tags: arrays, matlab

stuck on a Matlab problem- I have a large vector with time values of data acquisition however the time interval is irregular on some pieces so I need to interpolate the data on the missed time samples.

e.g `time = [1 2 3 4 5 6 9 10]` whereas I want `full_time = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]` so I can interpolate the corresponding missed out data

I want to create a vector with the same start and end values but with a regular interval and I wondered if there was a neater way than to use `full_time = [1:timeinterval:10]` so I wouldn't have to explicitly reference the numerical values of the first and last values by looking into the time vector?

Cheers for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the code to still work when you change values of `time` vector: use

```
full_time = time(1):timeinterval:time(end);
```

or, if `time` is not necessarily sorted,

```
full_time = min(time):timeinterval:max(time);
```